# Unable to retrieve attachments from a signed mail having ContentType as "application/pkcs7-mime; name=smime.p7m"

Tags: jakarta-mail, multipart, smime

I am trying to read a digitally signed mail from java code using multipart and mime messaging and fetch the attachments (xml, pdf, txt etc.,) and message details.
My code is working fine for mails having Content-Type as : **multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature";** 
But For few mails having Content-Type as : **application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data; name=smime.p7m** it is not fetching the attachments and message details. Can anyone explain what is the difference between both of them and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this issue myself, and although this question is three month old, I leave an answer with my findings, just in case.

Both kinds of messages are instances of S/MIME signed messages as specified in RFC2633 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2633).

The **multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature"** indicates a clear-signed message (section 3.4.3.3 of the RFC), meaning you can read the original message content without having S/MIME capabilities in your client code. Hence no problem with these.

The **application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data; name=smime.p7m** indicates an S/MIME signedData email (section 3.4.2) Your client code needs S/MIME capability in order to read the original message (even if you don’t care about the signature).

Easiest way (worked for me) is to use bouncycastle's SMIMESigned class (from the S/MIME API, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk15on), like this:

```
byte[] content = <the signed data's content as byte[]>;
ByteArrayDataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(content,"multipart/signed");
SMIMESigned signedData = new SMIMESigned(new MimeMultipart(dataSource));
MimeBodyPart bodyPart = signedData.getContent();
<you can process the body part as normal from here>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Dirk

Comment: Is there any possibility for the same to be done through Microsoft Exchange Web Services API?